# eigenvalue decomposition of structure tensor in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, structure, tensor, eigenvalue

I have a synthetic image. I want to do eigenvalue decomposition of local structure tensor (LST) of it for some edge detection purposes. I used the eigenvalues`l1` , `l2` and eigenvectors `e1` ,`e2` of LST to generate an adaptive ellipse for each pixel of image. Unfortunately I get unequal eigenvalues `l1` , `l2` and so unequal semi-axes length of ellipse for homogeneous regions of my figure:
[image: my image]

However I get good response for a simple test image:
[image: test image]

I don't know what is wrong in my code:

```
function [H,e1,e2,l1,l2] = LST_eig(I,sigma1,rw)

%  LST_eig - compute the structure tensor and its eigen
% value decomposition
%
%   H = LST_eig(I,sigma1,rw);
%
%   sigma1 is pre smoothing width (in pixels).
%   rw is filter bandwidth radius for tensor smoothing (in pixels).
%


n = size(I,1);
m = size(I,2);
if nargin<2
    sigma1 = 0.5;
end
if nargin<3
    rw = 0.001;
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% pre smoothing
J = imgaussfilt(I,sigma1);
% compute gradient using Sobel operator
Sch = [-3 0 3;-10 0 10;-3 0 3];
%h = fspecial('sobel');
gx = imfilter(J,Sch,'replicate');
gy = imfilter(J,Sch','replicate');

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% compute tensors

gx2 = gx.^2;
gy2 = gy.^2;
gxy = gx.*gy;

% smooth
gx2_sm = imgaussfilt(gx2,rw); %rw/sqrt(2*log(2))
gy2_sm = imgaussfilt(gy2,rw);
gxy_sm = imgaussfilt(gxy,rw);
H = zeros(n,m,2,2);
H(:,:,1,1) = gx2_sm; 
H(:,:,2,2) = gy2_sm; 
H(:,:,1,2) = gxy_sm; 
H(:,:,2,1) = gxy_sm; 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% eigen decomposition
l1 = zeros(n,m);
l2 = zeros(n,m);
e1 = zeros(n,m,2);
e2 = zeros(n,m,2);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:m
        Hmat = zeros(2);
        Hmat(:,:) = H(i,j,:,:);
        [V,D] = eigs(Hmat);
        D = abs(D);
        l1(i,j) = D(1,1); % eigen values
        l2(i,j) = D(2,2); 
        e1(i,j,:) = V(:,1); % eigen vectors
        e2(i,j,:) = V(:,2); 
    end
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

This is my ellipse drawing code:

```
% determining ellipse parameteres from eigen value decomposition of LST

M = input('Enter the maximum allowed semi-major axes length: ');
I = input('Enter the input data: ');

row = size(I,1);
col = size(I,2);
a = zeros(row,col);
b = zeros(row,col);
cos_phi = zeros(row,col);
sin_phi = zeros(row,col);


for m = 1:row
  for n = 1:col

    a(m,n) = (l2(m,n)+eps)/(l1(m,n)+l2(m,n)+2*eps)*M;
    b(m,n) = (l1(m,n)+eps)/(l1(m,n)+l2(m,n)+2*eps)*M;

    cos_phi1 = e1(m,n,1);
    sin_phi1 = e1(m,n,2);
    len = hypot(cos_phi1,sin_phi1);           
    cos_phi(m,n) = cos_phi1/len;
    sin_phi(m,n) = sin_phi1/len;

  end
end

%% plot elliptic structuring elements using parametric equation and superimpose on the image 


figure; imagesc(I); colorbar; hold on

t = linspace(0,2*pi,50);

for i = 10:10:row-10
  for j = 10:10:col-10
    x0 = j;
    y0 = i;

    x = a(i,j)/2*cos(t)*cos_phi(i,j)-b(i,j)/2*sin(t)*sin_phi(i,j)+x0;
    y = a(i,j)/2*cos(t)*sin_phi(i,j)+b(i,j)/2*sin(t)*cos_phi(i,j)+y0;

    plot(x,y,'r','linewidth',1);
    hold on
  end
end
```

This my new result with the Gaussian derivative kernel:
[image: gauss_derivative]

This is the new plot with `axis equal`:

[image: gauss_der_axis_eq]

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Thank you. I test 0.5, 1, 5, 8 for `rw` but I don't get the good result. yes it is not the Sobel filter, it's the Scharr filter. Are you sure the gaussian derivatives are better? you know, those ellipses are the structuring elements that i use for my purpose, I draw them to understand are they adaptive enough? I thought i should use `eigs` for the tensor.

Comment: I used `eig` instead of `eigs` but the result did not change, just run time decreased. what is Gaussian derivatives function in matlab?

Comment: Looking at your image, I noticed that your x any y axes are not scaled the same way. Is this on purpose? `axis equal` sets their scaling the same. This might explain why some of those ellipses are not don't line up with the structures in the image.

Comment: I think my ellipse drawing code is right. I added it to the question. I run code with a Gaussian derivative kernel and I got a more acceptable answer. I add the new plot to the question too.

Comment: Looks good. Again, using `axis equal` you'll get a better representation of the ellipses, they are rounder than they look in your image. You still have a band of high isotropy running down along the middle of the image, but maybe that's in the data? And where the curve is horizontal, I see vertical elongated ellipses, not sure why that is either. Running your code on a test image, I get good results (even with the Scharr filter and `eigs`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. for the band in the middle of the image, I checked my data. It is homogeneous all over the image, not just in the curve. with `axis equal` the ellipses look rounder but my image has not been plot well. I added it to the question. why the ellipses are elongated on the top and bottom of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test image similar to yours (probably less complicated) as follows:

```
pos = yy([400,500]) + 100 * sin(xx(400)/400*2*pi);
img = gaussianlineclip(pos+50,7) + gaussianlineclip(pos-50,7);
I = double(stretch(img));
```

(This requires [DIPimage](http://www.diplib.org) to run)

Then ran your `LST_eig` on it (`sigma1=1` and `rw=3`) and your code to draw ellipses (no change to either, except adding `axis equal`), and got this result:

[image]

I suspect some non-uniformity in some of the blue areas of your image, which cause very small gradients to appear. The problem with the definition of the ellipses as you use them is that, for sufficiently oriented patterns, you'll get a line even if that pattern is imperceptible. You can get around this by defining your ellipse axes lengths as follows:

```
a = repmat(M,size(l2)); % longest axis is always the same
b = M ./ (l2+1); % shortest axis is shorter the more important the largest eigenvalue is
```

The smallest eigenvalue `l1` is high in regions with strong gradients but no clear direction. The above does not take this into account. One option could be to make `a` depend on both energy and anisotropy measures, and `b` depend only on energy:

```
T = 1000; % some threshold
r = M ./ max(l1+l2-T,1); % circle radius, smaller for higher energy
d = (l2-l1) ./ (l1+l2+eps); % anisotropy measure in range [0,1]
a = M*d + r.*(1-d); % use `M` length for high anisotropy, use `r` length for high isotropy (circle)
b = r; % use `r` width always
```

This way, the whole ellipse shrinks if there are strong gradients but no clear direction, whereas it stays large and circular when there are only weak or no gradients. The threshold `T` depends on image intensities, adjust as needed.

You should probably also consider taking the square root of the eigenvalues, as they correspond to the variance.

**Some suggestions:**

1. You can write

   ```
   a = (l2+eps)./(l1+l2+2*eps) * M;
   b = (l1+eps)./(l1+l2+2*eps) * M;
   cos_phi = e1(:,:,1);
   sin_phi = e1(:,:,2);
   ```

   without a loop. Note that `e1` is normalized by definition, there is no need to normalize it again.
2. Use [Gaussian gradients](https://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22) instead of Gaussian smoothing followed by Sobel or Schaar filters. See [here](https://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/150) for some MATLAB implementation details.
3. Use `eig`, not `eigs`, when you need all eigenvalues. Especially for such a small matrix, there is no advantage to using `eigs`. `eig` seems to produce more consistent results. There is no need to take the absolute value of the eigenvalues (`D = abs(D)`), as they are non-negative by definition.
4. Your default value of `rw = 0.001` is way too small, a sigma of that size has no effect on the image. The goal of this smoothing is to average gradients in a local neighborhood. I used `rw=3` with good results.
5. Use DIPimage. There is a `structuretensor` function, Gaussian gradients, and a lot more useful stuff. [The 3.0 version (still in development)](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) is a major rewrite that improves significantly on dealing with vector- and matrix-valued images. I can write all of your `LST_eig` as follows:

   ```
   I = dip_image(I);
   g = gradient(I, sigma1);
   H = gaussf(g*g.', rw);
   [e,l] = eig(H);
   % Equivalences with your outputs:
   l1 = l{2};
   l2 = l{1};
   e1 = e{2,:};
   e2 = e{1,:};
   ```

Comment: Dear dr. Luengo: I'm so thankful for your great help. Your tips are always helpful to me.

Comment: I have some connection problem. Just one more point: I created your test image with DIPimage. It is `0` all over the image, not just in the curve. So its eigenvalues `l1, l2` are `0` in homogeneous regions. But my image has `0.188075529030993` value all over the image and has `
1.493765725651963e-05` somewhere and values near this `0.008912427070687` in the curve and values near this `0.736702531715232`  next to the curve. I think my data is complicated.

Comment: @bahar: Yes, indeed, my test image is quite simplistic. It's always good to test a method with a simplistic test image, before making it more complex. As I said, the method draws lines instead of ellipses if there is a clear orientation locally, even if it is caused by very low intensity fluctuations. This is why I suggested the alternative `a` and `b` computation, which should ignore those small fluctuations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, 2 more question: 1. I ran your short `LST_eig` code with DIPimage but I got this error : `Error using dip_image/eig (line 52)
Tensor must be 2x2 or 3x3`. I think the `H` in your code is not a tensor. it is a 500*500 matrix. 2. Do you have any idea about using `bilateral` filter instead of Gaussian smoothing. It is edge preserving filter.

Comment: @bahar: The input image `I` should be a `dip_image` object, sorry I forgot to mention that. Regarding smoothing—I have no idea if that would work and be useful, if you can of course try and see if it works for you. The output would show anisotropy, since in isotopic regions you are averaging would be over fewer pixels. You would have to be careful that the averaging gets the same kernel in each tensor component, if you apply the filter separately to each channel, the output will not be correct. You need to average the full tensor locally.

Comment: Oh, but do use the `structuretrnsor` function in DIPimage. The code in the answer was just to show off DIPimage tensor functionality. :)