# gradient of a volume in 3 dimensions using Gaussian derivative in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, gradient, gaussian, derivative

I want to compute gradient of a volume in MATLAB using Gaussian derivative. but I  could not. can any one help me please? I do this in a 2D image using this code:

```
k = gaussiankernel(sigma1,1); % first order derivative of a gaussian with std 
sigma1

gx = imfilter(I,k','replicate','conv');
gy = imfilter(I,k,'replicate','conv');
```

please help me. How can I compute `gz` using kernel `k`? or How can I extend this code to 3D?
Thank you in advance.

This is the code to generate adaptive ellipsoid using `structuretensor3d`:

```
function SE = AESE3(I,M,l1,l2,l3,phi3,theta3)
%I = input('Enter the input 3d volume: ');
%M = input('Enter the maximum allowed semi-major axes length: ');


% determining ellipsoid parameteres from eigen value decomposition of 3d
% structure tensor

row = size(I,1);
col = size(I,2);
hei = size(I,3);
SE = cell(row,col,hei);
padI = padarray(I,[M M M],'replicate','both');
padrow = size(padI,1);
padcol = size(padI,2);
padhei = size(padI,3);

[se_x,se_y,se_z] = meshgrid(-M:M,-M:M,-M:M);

for m = M+1:padrow-M
    for n = M+1:padcol-M
        for p = M+1:padhei-M
i = m-M;
j = n-M;
k = p-M;

a = (l1(i,j,k)+eps)/(l1(i,j,k)+l2(i,j,k)+l3(i,j,k)+3*eps)*M;
b = (l2(i,j,k)+eps)/(l1(i,j,k)+l2(i,j,k)+l3(i,j,k)+3*eps)*M;
c = (l3(i,j,k)+eps)/(l1(i,j,k)+l2(i,j,k)+l3(i,j,k)+3*eps)*M;

cos(phi3(i,j,k)) = cos_phi3;
sin(phi3(i,j,k)) = sin_phi3;
cos(theta3(i,j,k)) = cos_theta3;
sin(theta3(i,j,k)) = sin_theta3;

% defining structuring element for each pixel of image

se = ((se_x.*cos_theta3 - se_y.*sin_theta3.*cos_phi3 + 
se_z.*sin_theta3.*sin_phi3).^2)./a.^2+((se_x.*sin_theta3 + 
se_y.*cos_theta3.*cos_phi3 - se_z.*cos_theta3.*sin_phi3).^2)./b.^2+ 
((se_y.*sin_phi3 + se_z.*cos_phi3).^2)./c.^2 <= 1;

SE{i,j,k} = se;
        end
    end
end
end

Can I do this without zero padding?
```

Comment: What is the function `gaussiankernel`? It is not in any of the official MATLAB toolboxes. Please include the code here. Did you download it from somewhere? If so, please include the link.

Comment: You can also download [the DIPimage toolbox](http://www.diplib.org/), then the derivatives are `dx(I,sigma1)`, `dy(I,sigma1)` and `dz(I,sigma1)`. Or simply `gradientvector(I,sigma1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I don't have the link. I just have a mat file. I used `imgradientxyz` for derivatives. Is it proper? I actually want to extend `LST_eig` function to 3D to compute egienvalues and eigenvectors of structure tensor. I added code to the question but I don't know why I'm getting this error: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Comment: Yes, `imgradientxyz` seems to be OK. I Googled for "LST_eig" and found [an older question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221269/eigenvalue-decomposition-of-structure-tensor-in-matlab). Index out of bounds errors can be discovered by using the MATLAB debugger. Type `dbstop if error`, then run your code, and examine the variables on the line that fires the error to understand what your code is trying to do and why it's wrong. If you are interested in implementing this yourself that is OK, but you can also use the `structuretensor3d` function in DIPimage.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I downloaded DIPimage but unfortunately I couldn't create startup.m file in the default directory of MATLAB to automatically run 'dipstart.m'.

Comment: oh, I found what is wrong. I should use `D(1,1)` and `D(2,2)` and `D(3,3)` instead of `D(1,1,1)` and...

Comment: Indeed, `D` is a 3x3 matrix. The `startup.m` file should be in `Documents\MATLAB` or some such folder, whichever the place that MATLAB starts up in. Simply type `edit startup.m` when MATLAB launches.

Comment: sorry, I type `edit startup.m` but I get this error: `Error creating file start up .m in this current folder: Access is denied`

Comment: That is strange, what does `pwd` return? It should be a directory within your user directory. If not, you can setup your startup directory in the MATLAB preferences panel.

Comment: With delay and many thanks for your advice. I have two questions: 1- I used the  `structuretensor3d` function in DIPimage, but all the outputs are in the format of dip_image, not double, and I'm having difficulty in plotting and using them. How can I convert them to double? 2. How can I define the adaptive elliptical structuring element using the outputs of `structuretensor3d` function for any point in volume? Like what we defined for a 2D image before.

Comment: 1- If `img` is a `dip_image` object, then `double(img)` is a double array. 2- For example `[l1,phi1,theta1]=structuretensor3d(img,1,3,{'l1','phi1','theta1'})` returns in `l1` the largest eigenvalue at each pixel, and in `phi1,theta1` the angles of the corresponding eigenvector. This function does the eigendecomposition automatically.

Comment: If you want to compute the structure tensor itself, you can do (assuming `img` is a `dip_image` object): `g=gradient(img); S=g*g.'; S=gaussf(S,3); [V,D]=eig(S)`. Here `S` is the structure tensor, `V` the matrix with eigenvectors, and `D` the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues. `S(50,30,6)` is the matrix at the given pixel (using (x,y,z) indexing, not (row,column,plane)). `S{1,1}` corresponds to your `gx2_sm`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using your tips, I'm working on the code and I'll ask if I have any questions. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Highly late: The code I added to the question is right (particularly ellipsoid equation) to produce adaptive ellipsoidal structuring element for each point of the volume? I generated `l1`, `l2`, `l3`, `phi3` and `theta3` using `structuretensor3d` function.

Comment: Looks OK to me, but it's hard to read so maybe I missed something. Does it not yield the right result? You could improve readability by replacing `m-M` by a new variable (or simply loop `m=1:row`), and doing the indexing once, write lamdas and angles to temporary variables, and use those in the calculation. Anything you can come up with to make those expressions shorter would help readability... For efficiency, move the `meshgrid` call outside the loop, since it's always the same.

Comment: Oh, `phi3` and `theta3` are the angles for the 3rd (smallest) eigenvector. You would need the angles for the first or second eigenvector also (the 3rd set of angles can be computed from the other two).

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I run the code, but I could not see the three-dimensional results, i.e. ellipsoid generated per pixels. With your tips, I made some expressions shorter. I can replace loop with `m = 1:row`, but what about border pixels? I used `phi3` and `theta3` because I thought the smallest eigenvector is parallel to edge. Is the ellipsoid equation true?

Comment: I found the equation of the rotated ellipsoid and change it in the code. but I don't know why for all points of data `se` is a zero cube without 1. can you help me please?